# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::save()

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I created 'Log' class in app/models :

```
class Log extends Eloquent {

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }

}
```

When i try to save log object in my controller i got this error (`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log::save()` ) I thik because in (`app/config/app`) in providers laravel define Log class => `'Log'=> 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log',`.

How can i resolve this problem without change class name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the problem is indeed a conflict with the `Log` facade alias. To fix it use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php):

```
<?php namespace YourApp;

class Log extends Eloquent {

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('user');
    }

}
```

And then you can use your class like so:

```
$log = new YourApp\Log();
```

You could of course rename the alias name, but namespacing your classes is a much better approach.